# ACF default field group settings for "hide on screen"

Tags: wordpress, settings, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to set default settings for **style** and **hide on screen** settings within the field group settings.

[image]
[image]

I've found posts talking about modifying settings for individual ACF fields like the WYSIWYG or image fields like so.

```
add_filter( 'acf/get_valid_field', 'change_post_content_type');
function change_post_content_type( $field ) {
    if($field['type'] == 'wysiwyg') {
        $field['tabs'] = 'visual'; 
        $field['media_upload'] = 0;
    }
    if($field['type'] == 'image') {
        $field['preview_size'] = 'small';
    }
    if($field['type'] == 'style') {
        $field['style'] = 'seamless';
    }
    return $field; 
}
```

Using this overrides whatever is selected rather than setting the value as default but it's good enough for what I need.

The image and WYSIWG field work fine but I can't get it working on the field group setting fields. I don't think the `$field['type'] == 'style'` is correct but as it doesn't follow the same structure as the other fields I don't know what I should be using.

Any ideas?

**update**

I've found [this](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/group-options-acf_render_field_wrap-is-there-an-officiel-way-to-do-this/) but I can't figure out how to use it. The following doesn't work

```
add_action('acf/render_field_group_settings', 'change_field_group_settings', 10, 1);
function change_field_group_settings( $field_group ) {
    
    $field_group['style'] = 'seemless';
    $field_group['hide_on_screen'] = array('the_content');
    
    return $field_group;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need change your syntax to use proper formatting for *style* and *hide_on_screen*, for example:

```
'hide_on_screen' => array(
    0 => 'the_content',
),
```

Best practice would be to create a new Field Group in your WP CMS, publish it, and navigate to:
Custom Fields > Tools > (check the box for your Field Group) > Generate PHP

That way you can view the proper output.